# Wordpress function to get links using conditional current page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to code a navigation menu with custom links for other pages using conditional tags for excluding current page link.

```
<ul class="navs float-left">
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(11); ?>">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(15); ?>">Donation</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(13); ?>">Help</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(79); ?>">Terms</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Using WordPress function to be called as Template tag:

```
echo'<ul class="navs float-left">';
    if ( ! is_page(11) ){
      echo'<li><a href="'.echo get_page_link(11).'">About نحن؟</a></li>';
    }
    if ( ! is_page(15) ){
      echo'<li><a href="'.echo get_page_link(15).'">Donation</a></li>';
    }
    if ( ! is_page(16) ){
      echo'<li><a href="'.echo get_page_link(16).'">Help</a></li>';
    }
    if ( ! is_page(17) ){
      echo'<li><a href="'.echo get_page_link(17).'">Terms</a></li>';
    }
  echo'</ul>';
```

I need assistant to make the correct coding of the function as well as replacing the static anchored title with `the_title()` to auto output anchored page name.
Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Why just not use build in wordpress menu? There you can add custom links to. Or in Wordpress logic each these page you need another template to call another menu... Do wordpress way...

Comment: @KārlisMillers That won`t be necessary as menu items will not be modified after anymore.

Answer (score 2):

That was easy using PHP foreach function. Just giving a variable of included pages as ids array, then calling each page ID variables(link, title) with conditional tags:

```
$pages_id= array(11, 15, 13, 79, 17);
echo '<ul class="navs float-left">';
foreach ($pages_id as $id) {
  if (!is_page( $id )) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_page_link($id).'">'.get_the_title($id).'</a></li>';
  }
}
echo '</ul>';
```